# Actionscript TextFormat resets when changing TextField.text

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, textfield

I have a `TextField` that is formatted with bold and blue. However, when I change `TextField.text`, the formatting of the `textfield` resets and I have to `setTextFormat` again.

This is the code I use to set my `TextField`. `myText` is the variable for my `TextField`. (This is just part of my code; it is part of a function for my `EventListener`.)

```
yourName = body_txt.text;  
myText.text = "This is the new text";
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In AS3 you will want to use the `defaultTextFormat` property of `TextField` object's.

Answer (score 4):

Tyler's correct. More specifically:

```
myTextField.defaultTextFormat = myTextField.getTextFormat();
myTextField.text = "Sample text.";
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

You should use `setNewTextFormat` instead, this will affect future changes.

Or, optionally (if you already have some text), apply new format to both properties:

```
var myTextField:TextField = new TextField();
myTextField.text = "Chunky bacon" ;

var newFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
newFormat.color = 0xFF0000;
newFormat.size = 18;
newFormat.underline = true;
newFormat.italic = true;

myTextField.setTextFormat( newFormat ) ; // Applies to current value – "Chunky bacon"
myTextField.setNewTextFormat( newFormat ) ; // Applies to future changes - " Hello World"

myTextField.text += " Hello World" ;
```

Comment: If I recall correctly, setNewTextFormat is a AS2 language method only.